# Logback prints logs without adhering to logback-spring.xml until after the banner is printed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

When I run my Spring Boot application, Logback keeps printing logs with settings from my logback-spring.xml not applied until after the banner is printed (everything before the banner is formatted differently and I want to avoid having it be printed):

```
2019-03-04 13:15:25.151  INFO   --- [           main] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : 
2019-03-04 13:15:25.157  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.t.c.support.AbstractContextLoader    : 
2019-03-04 13:15:25.158  INFO   --- [           main] t.c.s.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils : 
2019-03-04 13:15:25.298  INFO   --- [           main] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : 
2019-03-04 13:15:25.401  INFO   --- [           main] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : 
2019-03-04 13:15:25.430  INFO   --- [           main] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : 

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.2.RELEASE)

2019-03-04 13:15:25.886 DEBUG 7484 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : 
2019-03-04 13:15:25.903 DEBUG 7484 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : 
2019-03-04 13:15:25.904 DEBUG 7484 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : 
2019-03-04 13:15:25.904 DEBUG 7484 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : 
2019-03-04 13:15:25.905 DEBUG 7484 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : 
2019-03-04 13:15:25.922 DEBUG 7484 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : 
2019-03-04 13:15:25.937 DEBUG 7484 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : 
2019-03-04 13:15:26.004 DEBUG 7484 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   :
```

I've read on the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.0/reference/htmlsingle/#features.logging.logback-extensions) that:

> Because the standard logback.xml configuration file is loaded too early, you cannot use extensions in it. You need to either use logback-spring.xml or define a logging.config property.

I'm assuming the default configurations are loaded earlier than Spring Boot initializes the logging configuration. If so, is there any way I can tell logback to disable all of its logs until Spring Boot takes over?

I have also looked into [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53421136/1934402) and implemented it, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Is it because I'm using Spring Boot 3.2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create `logback.xml` file in `src/main/resources` and change logging level to ERROR.

Alternatively, you can try to use springProperty tag.

> Sometimes, we need to access values from the application.properties file in the logging configuration. In this situation, we use the springProperty element in the Logback configuration.
>
> The springProperty element is similar to Logback’s standard property
> element. However, we can determine the source of the property from the
> environment rather than specifying a direct value.